# Gmail/Facebook/Hotmail not opening in Firefox/IE on Windows 7 Home

Tags: gmail

I am unable to open Gmail/Facebook/Hotmail on Firefox/IE on Widows 7 Home. I just unboxed a brand new hp laptop with Norton Security Suite running inside. I get following error message on Firefox. Please help.

The connection has timed out

The server at www.google.com is taking too long to respond.

```
*   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
      moments.

*   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
      connection.

*   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
      that Firefox is permitted to access the Web
```

Comment: is it only for these 3 sites??? that error suggests that there was no internet connection and nothing else.. that's the standard error.

Comment: 1) Is it only for these 3 sites? 2) Have you tried disabling the firewall that comes with Norton Security Suite?

Comment: This should go to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I am not sure about the generality of the solution but it worked for me at least. Uninstall firefox and re-install it but this time you will not import any settings from IE. That's it. It worked for me like a charm.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like you have IE set up to use a proxy server, then. If Firefox is importing that setting, it won't work either. Check your Internet Options (from IE, Tools->Internet Options).

Comment: Yeah, IE was using a proxy server and the same proxy server is being used by the fresh install of firefox because it is the only way for me to get to the internet. Perhaps IE doesn't like other browsers too to open gmail. :)